# Find the logic for the two tds combination

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

[image]

How do I create a XPath so that it can validate 'Aetna' and 'passed'  if we have two passed coverage but distinguish with coverage name?

[image]

How do I create an path for passed hyperlink so that its name is aetna and validated is passed?

Comment: Posting images of code or markup is not helpful to get answers. Please post your code or html as text.

Comment: Can you put relevant html code of the table at here, the picture can't tell us the table html structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below xpath to locate the verification status (passed/failed) based on "Payor" name :

```
//tr[@class='PanelDetail']/td[text()='AETNA'][1]/following-sibling::td/a
```

**Explanation:**

`//tr[@class='PanelDetail']/td[text()='AETNA'][1]` It will locate the Payor(as column name showing in your image).So here pass the name whose status you want to get.`/following-sibling::td/a` will locate the Passed Link.

You can get the text and use if condition to compare text whether it is "Passed" or some other

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//tr[@class='PanelDetail']/td[text()='AETNA'][1]/following-sibling::td/a")).Text
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding on to NarendraR's comment. The xpath could be modified to capture the link text as well. So the xpath should be

```
//tr[@class='PanelDetail']/td[text()='AETNA'][1]/following-sibling::td/a[text()='Passed']
```

This will locate the link with the text Passed and validate the Aetna text as well